# Do I have to enable Firebase if I want to connect to my Cloud Firestore database from outside of Google cloud products?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Till now I was using service account to connect to my Firestore database (Firebase is not enabled) from within Google products like Cloud Functions or Colab.

Now I need to connect to Firestore from html page opened in my browser. Is it possible without enabling Firebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the [Google Cloud Firestore](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/firestore) NodeJS SDK is meant to be used on server side only. You can use [Firebase Web SDK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase) along with [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/products/auth) and [Firebase Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/overview) to support serverless app architectures where clients connect directly to your Firestore database.

You don't necessarily have to use Firebase Auth. However, it might be a good idea to restrict access and allow only public content to be accessible without authentication.

You can follow the [quickstart](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart) in the documentation to setup the client SDK.